# OS X 10.8.4 - Launchd and auto-enroll certificate script not working

Tags: macos, bash, certificate, launchd

First time here and already in trouble... so here's the deal :
- Mac OS X 10.8.4
- SCCM 2012
- XServe 10.7 + DeployStudio 1.6.2

I deploy my iMacs using DeployStudio. As a part of the deployment process, the Macs are binded to AD & OD. I need also to install the Microsoft SCCM 2012 client. In order for the iMacs to properly communicate with SCCM and being furtherly managed, I need them to enroll a certificate at first boot. My colleague and myself tried a couple of different methods, no luck yet.
So what we currently have in mind is to copy a plist in the LaunchDemons folder and the enroll script in another location to be run by launchd. Problem is : doesn't work... and no logs whatsoever ! :confused:

Here's the plist :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
  <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.sccm.enrollcert</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array>
    <string>/usr/bin/enroll</string>
   </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
   <true/>
 </dict>
</plist>
```

Very simple as you can see...

And here's the enroll.sh script :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn /usr/bin/CMEnroll -s SCCM.DOMAIN.local -ignorecertchainvalidation -u "DOMAIN\ACCOUNT"
expect "Please enter your password."
send "passwd\n"
sleep 50
```

So as you can see it pretty simple... but for some funny reason it doesn't work at all.

Is there something we're missing by using "expect"/"spawn" in a launchd script like that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ...Anyone ? Kinda desperate....